# Scala Generics - Overloaded method

Tags: spring, scala, generics, spring-data, aspectj

Considering the given code:

```
    val repository =
      context.getBean(
        Introspector.decapitalize(t.getClass.getSimpleName).replace("C", "E").concat("Repository"))
```

and that my repositories have a String as Serializable.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[_, String]].save(getObject(t))
```

This one works fine:

```
repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[_, String]].findAll()
```

But I don't know how to put that above to work.

Assuming the method getObject(t) is retuning the correct object to be persisted and since it's a Spring Data Repository, there are 2 save method. One that accept a single entity and another for a list of entities and it says overloaded method value save.

What I have tried so far:

I saw in another thread to force the method with a type, something like this:

```
repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[_, String]].save(getObject(t) : TYPE)
```

This is ok if I knew the type and also my method getObject should return that same type.

Here is my getObject method which I return the object itself without any specific type:

```
@throws[IOException]
  def getObject[T](t : T) = {
    objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t), getClazz(t))
  }
```

So I was trying to get the type like this:

```
val m = Manifest.classType(getClazz(t))
    type TYPE = m.type
```

Looks good if I force my object to this type using `getObject(t) : TYPE` but I don't know how to use this same type in my getObject method to be returned.

Anyway, I don't even know if this is the best approach to do this, invoking a generic repository and save a generic object.

Just to understand what I'm trying to do, I'm using a aspect to intercept a Cassandra entity to be persisted, then get it and turn into a ElasticSearch entity to save a json(thats why the getObject(t)) and replicate into ElasticSearch.

Here is the full aspect class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
class ElasticAop {

  @Autowired val context : ApplicationContext = null

  val objectMapper : ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.service.cassandra.*.post(..)) && args(t)")
  def getPointcutPost[T](t : T) : Unit = {}

  @throws[Throwable]
  @Before("getPointcutPost(t)")
  def elasticSaveAspect[T](joinPoint: JoinPoint, t: T) = {
    val m = Manifest.classType(getClazz(t))
    type TYPE = m.type

    val repository =
      context.getBean(
        Introspector.decapitalize(t.getClass.getSimpleName).replace("C", "E").concat("Repository"))

    repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[_, String]].findAll()
    repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[_, String]].save(getObject(t))
  }

  @throws[ClassNotFoundException]
  def getClazz[T](t : T) = {
    val className = t.getClass.getName.replace("cassandra", "elastic").replace("C", "E")
    Class.forName(className)
  }

  @throws[IOException]
  def getObject[T](t : T) = {
    objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t), getClazz(t))
  }

}
```

**EDITED**

Even setting up a type return in my getObject to Address and then setting the save method as follow save(getObject(t) : Address) give me the same overloaded error.

**EDITED**

I just figured out it's a limitation and a possible work around is to create a factory or something like this.
Then I created a service with a saveOrUpdate method:

```
trait ElasticGenericService[T <: ElasticGenericKey, R <: ElasticsearchRepository[T, String]] {

  var r : R = _

  def saveOrUpdate(t: T) = r.save(t)

}
```

and now I'm getting a cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Address cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can see here:

- `getObject[T](t : T)` returns existential type `_1` and actually kills all type checks, as you choosing the class in runtime
- `ElasticsearchRepository[_, String].save` require existential type `_2` to be passed to the save method, so `_1` doesn't fit

Possible solution:

```
repository.asInstanceOf[ElasticsearchRepository[Any, String]].save(getObject(t).asInstanceOf[Any]) //getClass will work with runtime class instead of Any, so should be fine
```

Another solution (saving existential type):

```
def getObject[T](t : T) = {
    objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(t), getClazz(t)).asInstanceOf[T]
} //assuming T is an existential - it will return same existential as you passed
```